# jQuery .offset() inside SVG is not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, svg, safari

I have a map SVG with some interactive points. Hovering the point display an HTML `div` positioned nearby the point.

So I'm using **jQuery** `.offset()` inside the SVG. It's working great in **Chrome** and **Firefox** but it doesn't seem to work in **Safari**. It's always returning

```
{top: 0, left: 0}
```

**HTML/SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1211" height="1198">
    (...)
    <g data-city="amsterdam">
    <path/>
  </g>
    <g data-city="london">
    <path/>
  </g>
    <g data-city="paris">
    <path/>
  </g>
  (...)
</svg>
```

**jQuery**

```
    // -- Open infosbox --
  $('[data-city]').on('touchstart mouseover', function(){
    var city = $(this).attr('data-city');
    var cityEl = $('.city--'+city);
    var offset = setOffsetPosition($(this), cityEl);

    $('.city').removeClass('active');
    cityEl.offset(offset).addClass('active');
  });

  // -- Close infosbox --
  $('[data-city]').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.city').removeClass('active');
  });

    function setOffsetPosition($this, $el) {
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var elW = $el.width();
        var elH = $el.height();
        var marginB = 20;
        offset.top = offset.top - (elH + marginB);
        offset.left = offset.left - (elW/2);
        return offset;
    }
```

**Full Code**

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/hellodie/pen/xMeqBo) to see the full code, any help is welcome

Comment: Thanks @Pete ! I've just updated my post. Hope it's better like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If jQuery was a library aimed at SVG support, I would call this a jQuery bug. But it isn't, so they can say it is an upstream bug that Safari has to fix.

What happens is [this part](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#L93) of the jQuery code:

```
    // Return zeros for disconnected and hidden (display: none) elements (gh-2310)
    // Support: IE <=11 only
    // Running getBoundingClientRect on a
    // disconnected node in IE throws an error
    if ( !elem.getClientRects().length ) {
        return { top: 0, left: 0 };
    }
```

This is considered to be a fallback for IE to make sure no error is thrown for disconnected DOM nodes. But it uses the interface `Element.getClientRects()`, which for Safari returns an empty list if the element is in the SVG namespace.

The way around this is to use the rest of the code directly. You know the selected nodes are part of the document, so the error mentioned cannot happen:

```
function setOffsetPosition($this, $el) {
    var rect = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var win = $this[0].ownerDocument.defaultView;

    var elW = $el.width();
    var elH = $el.height();
    var marginB = 20;
    return {
         top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset - (elH + marginB),
         left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset - (elW/2)
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @ccprog ! Thank you for your help and explanations. Your code is working great for the offset.left but for some reason, the offset.top is not correct. I tried some operations and others methods to get the right result but no luck. I'll keep trying to make it work but if you have any ideas to solve the problem, it's more than welcome :) Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong track. I thought `.getScreenCTM()` would not take scrolling into account, which would make its use easier to use than `getBoundingClientRect()`. But this isn't the case, and so the jQuery solution is fine - you only have to bypass the error condition. See edit.