# Find position of an SVG with jQuery .offset() not working in safari

Tags: jquery, svg, offset

This code is working fine in chrome

```
    $("#el").hover(function () {
    let position = $(this).offset();
    $('#popover').css(position);
    });
```

But offset() always return this in safari :

```
{top: 0, left: 0}
```

#el is a svg circle

```
<circle id="el"  cx="500" cy="153" r="50"></circle>
```

Is this a problem with jQuery?

Working exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/82syz54m/1/

In chrome :
[image]

In Safari :
[image]

Comment: does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790402/jquery-offset-inside-svg-is-not-working-in-safari

Comment: It seems to be the same problem but I can't find how to adapt the solution to my use case

Comment: I add an exemple in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is compatible with all browsers:

```
$("#el").hover(function () {
const circle = document.getElementById('el').getBoundingClientRect();
const position = { left: circle.left, top: circle.top };
$('#popover').css(position);
console.log(position)
});
```